# @RequestMapping does not map the URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new in `Spring MVC`. I created a WebApplication in `NetBeans 8.2` with `Spring-MVC 4.0.1`. I use annotation config and auto scan. The project deploys fine but the @RequestMapping does not map any controller methods. There is just only one URL `/index` mapped to the `indexController` in the `applicationContext.xml`. The server logs shows that the controller created but the URL does not mapped.

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.product"/>
    <!--bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.url}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" /-->

    <!-- ADD PERSISTENCE SUPPORT HERE (jpa, hibernate, etc) -->

</beans>
```

The dispatcherServlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

The MyController.java:

```
package com.company.product.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyController
{
  public MyController()
  {
    System.out.println( "#### MyController created" );
  }

  @RequestMapping( value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET )
  public String indexHandler_GET( ModelMap model_ )
  {
    System.out.println( "####indexHandler_GET called" );
    return "index";
  }
}
```

The server log:

```
Info:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
Info:   WebModule[/WebApplication2] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.3.2 ( 20170627-2139 e63598abf2ed2bb1a24674f308a734e0dce18a72) for context '/WebApplication2'
Info:   WebModule[/WebApplication2] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Info:   Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Info:   Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri May 25 23:23:04 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Info:   Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Info:   JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Info:   #### MyController created
Info:   Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 448 ms
Info:   WebModule[/WebApplication2] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Info:   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Info:   Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri May 25 23:23:04 CEST 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Info:   Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
Info:   Mapped URL path [/index.htm] onto handler 'indexController'
Info:   FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 137 ms
Info:   Loading application [WebApplication2] at [/WebApplication2]
Info:   WebApplication2 was successfully deployed in 1,146 milliseconds.
```

Could anybody help me why does it not map the URL when the controller created (the autoscan works)?

Comment: prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop> is there something wrong ? it may be "index.html"

Comment: I see you are using jsp as viewResolver.

Comment: @haticeSigirci The `web.xml` `server-mapping` contains `/*htm`

Comment: Could you look at this https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-dispatcherservlet-tutorial/

Comment: If you're new to Spring MVC, don't use obsolete versions (or follow an obsolete tutorial such as this). Spring is now on version **5.0**, with many of us using 4.3 for the moment. [Start with Spring Boot](https://start.spring.io) and the Spring Getting Started guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should add this to your context file to enable mvc.

`xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"`

`http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd`

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: I'm unable to create the mvc namespace. `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc` with location `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd`

Comment: What is the problem you are getting?

Comment: if I declare the namespace as like above, the IDE can't recognize it as a possible one. The element marked as invalid. It does not list the element in the mvc namespace just as like in the context one when I press ctrl-space after the `<` sign.

Comment: Try to declare the namespace, and then below paste the two other addresses to specify the location(check the update)

Comment: I used them yet, but the IDE bahaves strange. After that I just edited back and forth the other namespaces and now its working. It is a strange error... Thank you very much. You save me a lot of time. :)

Answer (score 1):

SpringBoot has made it easier, now you don't need to figth with xml files and you can create a spring web project with almost cero configuration, take a look at 
[Spring-building restful services](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a comment.

Comment: @Bitman Mostly true, but it's *almost* an answer: The real answer is "don't do this and use Boot instead".